# Best C type strategy for writing apps for iOS and Mac OS X

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, cocoa, 32bit-64bit

I'm writing an OpenGL(ES) app for iOS and Mac OS X simultaneously. Some parts of the code are platform-specific, and I use conditional compiling, but most of it is common to both platforms.

I started to develop my code in iOS. When I first tried to compile for the Mac, I realized that on the desktop, basic cocoa C types such as `CGFloat` and `NSUInteger` are 64 bit (i.e., `double` and `unsigned long` respectively, instead of `float` and `unsigned int`), so I got lots of "implicit downcast warnings" when:

1. I assigned a `CGFloat` to a `GLfloat`
2. I `NSLog()`'ed an `NSUInteger` using `%u`

Regarding #1, I could switch to using `float` instead of `CGFloat` everywhere, but I also need `CGSize`, `CGRect`, `CGPoint` so that would cause problems too.

Regarding #2, I could switch to using `uint` instead of `NSUInteger`, but cocoa uses `NSUInteger` everywhere (e.g. `[NSArray count]`).

What is the best strategy (or advice), regarding basic C types, to write code that is the cleanest, and compiles without lots of warnings on both iOS and OS X?

Comment: ...aaaand Apple announces iOS transition to 64 bits!!! The plot thickens!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the fact that iOS now has a 64 bit architecture too, I've since found that using explicit types wherever possible is the best option. The Game Center framework does exactly this with scores (`int_64t`). Core Audio, on the other hand, seems to use the defined types `SInt32`, `Uint64`, etc.
Getting floats from `CGPoint`/`CGRect` to pass to OpenGL ES could prove a bit more tricky, though...

In addition, I would recommend reading [Apple's transition guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaTouch64BitGuide/ConvertingYourAppto64-Bit/ConvertingYourAppto64-Bit.html) end to end.